# How to set up a distributed worker pool with Celery and RabbitMQ

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I'm still really new to this kind of thing so it's entirely possible that I've got this wrong.

I am trying to set up a distributed task system. I have a Django webapp that is generating tasks using Celery. Right now, I have the webapp, the worker, and RabbitMQ running all on the same server. I would like to distribute this out to several servers.

As I *currently* understand it, I should be able to have my webapp generating tasks, handing them off to the message queue -- which is its own server -- and then workers distributed across any number of servers will consume tasks from that queue. I know how to tell my Django app which server is the broker, but how do I start worker threads on the worker servers and instruct them where to consume tasks from? I'm totally lost -- I don't even know where to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run your worker code (async_tasks.py) like this:

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery('tasks', broker=broker_url)

@app.task(queue='queue_name')
def async_compute_something(input):
    # do something 
    return "Result"
```

on other machines using this command :

```
celery -A async_tasks worker -Q queue_name
```

Note that you have set the url of the broker correctly and not `localhost`